# How do I hide AutoQuery endpoints in metadata page on external service?

Tags: servicestack

I have two services, service A and service B.  Service A calls Service B, so I have added a reference to service B's service model into service A.  The issue I am running into, is that any AutoQuery operations for service B is displayed in service A's metadata.  The other operations for service B do not show up, only the AutoQuery ones.  Is there some way to hide these operations from service B in service A's metadata page.

See image below, I have highlighted the offending request objects.

[image: Operations that should not be there.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack works out which Service Models to include in its Services metadata via type references. 2 different Service Models shouldn't have a reference to each other and ideally there should only be 1 Service Model per App.

So you should decouple any ServiceModel Assembly references, which [should be dependency-free](https://docs.servicestack.net/physical-project-structure#servicemodel-project), i.e. the only references your ServiceModel Assembly should have is to the dep/impl-free **ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll** which you can do by copying the types you need from the other Assembly into your ServiceModel as separate classes where you can use [Auto Mapping](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) to copy over the properties between the different Types in different assemblies.

Comment: That makes sense, having the service model be dependency free. What if, the different service models were referenced in the service interface?  They are technically not coupled.  Basically, I have one service that will be calling multiple downstream services via the service gateway.  Is there a good working example of how this should be done.  I want to minimize the amount of code I have to write the number of locations i need to define these operations.

Comment: @cletisgipson it's fine if it's only used within the Service implementation and doesn't leak out into the public Service Contract returned by the Services.